# Can Magento handle large numbers of product prices

Tags: magento, dataset, mage

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2, with approximately 4,000 product items and 3000 customer accounts, recently I have been tasks with uploading a large amount of customer prices. The prices will be held against the product as group prices, and the customers price will be determined by the group they belong to - all standard magento and all working fine.

However the requirement will mean i will be required to upload 650 customer groups, and then associate a product price with each group

This yeilds 650 * 4000 = 2,600,000 - A lot of prices!

I'm aware that this will take some time to complete as a process the question is can Magento handle this number of prices?

thanks

Comment: sure magento is able to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is able to handle this. Of course it depends on the hardware also :).
There might be some problems in the add-to-cart and checkout process. by problems I mean it might slow down the process a little.
For product listing Magento uses the index tables for prices (and others) so this shouldn't be an issue.
By the way...your indexing process will take longer. You might not be able to run it from the backend (but that is not recommended anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the response, as it turns out I decided to go down the route of using category based discounts instead, as I can achieve lots of prices with a lot less hassle!

Comment: After further investigation I have found a problem, I have in code uploaded 450 customer group specific prices for a stock item, now I am unable to open the item in the back end. Other items open fine (although they do not have a large number of prices against them). Can anyone suggest a reason for this? thanks